# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this issue that I can't seem to figure out. I am posting data to my controller. The controller declaration looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(string Title, string Description, string Payment, string Adress, string ZIP, float Longitude, float Latitude)
```

Using Fiddler, the posted data looks like this

[image: Fiddler posted data]

I get this error message when posting:

> The parameters dictionary contains a `null` entry for parameter 'Longitude' of non-nullable type 'System.Single' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, Single, Single)' in 'GjortWebRole.Controllers.MyController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>       Parameter name: parameters

Comment: could you show us how you call this action method?

Comment: It can be an encoding issue. What is your brower/server culture? Is the Longitude value `15.628` a valid number with your culture? Try to send `15,628`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285819/jquery-asp-net-mvc-passing-float-number), MVC doesn't come with a `ModelBinder` for floats out of the box. You'll have to create your own if you want actions to accept float arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the parameters table, you send the city value(String) in the order of longitude(float) parameter. Try to add the city parameter to your action method before the longitude parameter.

```
public ActionResult Create(string Title, string Description, string Payment, string Adress, string ZIP,string City, float Longitude, float Latitude)
```

**UPDATE**

according to your comments, The `Create` method declaration should be as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection myform)
{
   String Title = myform["Title"];//title is the name of html tag
   Strign ZIP = myform["ZIP"];//ZIP is the name of html tag
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Does the order really matter? I added the City-parameter to the action method arguments list, and it's the same order as the post now, but with the same result :/

Comment: how you call this action method?

Comment: It is called through a form posting data, where "My" is the controller and "Create" is the action.

    `<form action="/My/Create" id="createjob" method="post">`

Comment: did you decorate `Create` method with `HttpPost` attribute? if no, try to do.

Comment: MVC binds argument values to action parameters using the names of the arguments and whatever data the model binding system can get out of the registered `ValueProvider`s. The order of arguments in posted data is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes i did, gonna try to do it as you describes above.

Comment: It didn't work with FormCollection, the array only contains the posted data field titles, not the actual data. Have a look at this image http://piclair.com/data/v96uq.jpg

Comment: The images shows the keys not the values of these keys,each key have its own value which posted from your view

Comment: check this [post](http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/iterate-through-system-web-mvc-formcollection/) to know more about `FormCollection`